# dismissing search display controller keyboard

Tags: iphone, search, keyboard, controller

I am using search display controller and a search bar. When i click inside the serach bar the keyboard appears. When i navigate away to another page , the keyboard does not disappear and stays in the same page. Can you please help me ?

Thanks,
Andy.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do something like [searchBar resignFirstResponder] perhaps in – (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked: (UISearchBar *) searchBar

Comment: Tried using [searchbar resignFirstResponder] in view will disappear and view did disappear but no use :(

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints or NSLog statements to ensure that the call to `resignFirstResponder` is actually being made? I ask because I used to frequently forget to define `viewWillDisappear:` with its second argument, `animated:`, so it wouldn't be called. Caused me all sorts of confusion before I figured out how to debug effectively.